# Setting up Laravel app on Heroku with MSSQL database- Missing Driver

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, heroku

I am a student and current building a web application for my project.

While trying to host my Laravel application to Heroku my biggest problem at the moment is with the app failing to connect to the MSSQL database, I am using the MSSQL addon for Heroku.

it shows the error when I try to run the app via the App link

**"could not find driver (SQL: select top 1 * from [sessions] where [id] = [idstring])"**

I've had a similar issue before while setting up the app to run on local. Solved that by downloading the needed drivers on my local system. Now I am lost as to how to do the same for the hosted app on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Your config/database.php should look something like:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
]
```